# Почему может происходить выход из учетной записи при подключении по RDP к Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Подключаюсь к серверу на Windows 10 по RDP и работаю с ним.
Иногда (1-2 раза в день) происходит выход из учетной записи,
с закрытием всех открытых программ естественно, ничего сохранить не успеваешь.

По началу думал - перезагрузка компа, но другие учетные записи на этом же сервере - работают параллельно без перезагрузок.
Значит происходит именно выход из учетки с закрытием всех процессов.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ограничения сеанса проверили: время логона У/З, лимит длительности сессии(сеанса) для У/З? Какое решение было использовано, чтобы преодолеть лицензионное ограничение по использованию RDP-сервера одним пользователем?

Comment: @Daemon-5 одновременно только один пользователь подключен к машине - я, Другой пользователь там в фоновом режиме работает. Параметры по ограничению сеанса не знаю где посмотреть

Comment: **одновременно только один пользователь подключен к машине - я, Другой пользователь там в фоновом режиме работает** - это противоречивые заявления. Ещё раз, в единицу времени может быть активным только один сеанс пользователя: RDP или консоль. Это лицензионные ограничения от Microsoft, реализованные системно.

Comment: В фоновом режиме - без RDP я имел ввиду. Одновременно только один пользователь по RDP и подключен.Лимиты длительности сессий в Windows 10 найти не могу, походу только для серверных версий можно менять их

Comment: В Win7.Pro можно задать лимиты RDP с помощью **Редактора локальной групповой политики**. В Win10 - аналогичный интерфейс:Конфигурация компьютера  → Административные шаблоны  → Компоненты Windows  → Службы удаленных рабочих столов  → Ограничение сеансов по времени. Там можно задать ограничение для активных сеансов и принудительное завершение активного сеанса

Comment: @Daemon-5 Нашел в gpedit.msc эти параметры. Изменил состояния с "Не задано" на "Отключено".
Мож вправду это решит проблему.